# How To Add Selected Product Data In Database?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-grid

I Have Used One Grid Serializer Module. In This Module, One Tab "Select Product"  in This Tab Has Display Product Grid  If Check box Has Select (Select Multiple Also) And Click Save Item, Then Record Should Saved Another Table  It is My ImageslideController.php Coding

```
        <?php

        class Chilly_Imageslide_Adminhtml_ImageslideController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
        {

            protected function _initAction()
            {
                $this->loadLayout()
                    ->_setActiveMenu('imageslide/items')
                    ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
                return $this;
            }   

            public function indexAction() {
                $this->_initAction();       
                $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('imageslide/adminhtml_imageslide'));
                $this->renderLayout();
            }
         public function productAction(){

                $this->loadLayout();
                $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.grid')
                ->setProducts($this->getRequest()->getPost('products', null));
                $this->renderLayout();
            }
            public function productGridAction()
            {

                $this->loadLayout();
                $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.grid')
                    ->setProducts($this->getRequest()->getPost('products', null));
                $this->renderLayout();
            }
            public function editAction()
            {
                $imageslideId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                $imageslideModel  = Mage::getModel('imageslide/imageslide')->load($imageslideId);

                if ($imageslideModel->getId() || $imageslideId == 0) {

                    Mage::register('imageslide_data', $imageslideModel);

                    $this->loadLayout();
                    $this->_setActiveMenu('imageslide/items');

                    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
                    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

                    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

                    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('imageslide/adminhtml_imageslide_edit'))
                         ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('imageslide/adminhtml_imageslide_edit_tabs'));

                    $this->renderLayout();
                } else {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('imageslide')->__('Item does not exist'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                }
            }

            public function newAction()
            {
                $this->_forward('edit');
            }

            public function saveAction()
            {
                if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
                    try {
                        $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                        if(isset($postData['links'])){
                            $products = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($data['links']['products']); //Save the array to your database
                        }
                        //exit;
                        $imageslideModel = Mage::getModel('imageslide/imageslide');

                        $imageslideModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                            ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                            ->setCId($postData['c_id'])
                            ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                            ->save();
                        var_dump($products);
                        //var_dump($postData);exit;
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setimageslideData(false);

                        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                        return;
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setimageslideData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                        return;
                    }
                }
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }

            public function deleteAction()
            {
                if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
                    try {
                        $imageslideModel = Mage::getModel('imageslide/imageslide');

                        $imageslideModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                            ->delete();

                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
                        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                    }
                }
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
            /**
             * Product grid for AJAX request.
             * Sort and filter result for example.
             */
            public function gridAction()
            {
                $this->loadLayout();
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(
                       $this->getLayout()->createBlock('imageslide/adminhtml_imageslide_grid')->toHtml()
                );
            }
        }
```

I M USes Two Table One Is, 1.imageslide , 2.newsproduct in Second Table Record Should Be Stored.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you already getting the values

```
$currproduct='';
if(isset($postData['links'])){
      $products = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($data['links']['products']); //Save the array to your database
      $currproduct= implode(',',$products);
     }
 //exit;
$imageslideModel = Mage::getModel('imageslide/imageslide');

$imageslideModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                        ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                        ->setCId($postData['c_id'])
                        ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                        ->save();
 if($currproduct){ //add it heree  }
```

Comment: It Is for The Table 1, i wan't to store record in second table,  that process how to do?

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki `$currproduct` is your data save it other table simply

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply.. I Found The Solution, But As Per My Above Image, If i Select Producs From Product Grid, And Click Save Item, Then Its Selected Record Can Stored In My Second Table How To Do That? Insert Record Only Selected Record !!!

Comment: In my ImageslideController.php has any condition write for saving data at another table?

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki added the condition for that

Comment: Can You Please Tell Me Which Condition Can we Write????

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki you can check product are selected `if($currproduct){ //add it heree  }` with this condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50510/discussion-between-rushikesh-solanki-and-qaisar-satti).